# Is there a pre-built Angular component similar to JTable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, crud

AngularJS seems like a fantastic system, but I'm curious about prebuilt components for enterprise style CRUD.  JQueryUI has the excellent JTable, and there's also datatable and jqGrid.  Basically, I'm wondering if there is an automatic table with server side CRUD/REST backend support and common features such as sorting, paging, filtering, add/remove and so forth.  If nothing exists in Angular, are there recommendations about the best non-angular native AJAX based CRUD tables library to integrate into an Angular project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah for what it is worth, I ended up using Kendo UI's DataGrid, which does in fact do all the things I was asking about, and as of the most recent version, has a vendor-supported Angular integration library.  Thanks for the other answers though!

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out ng-grid?  I think it has some of what you want.

http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/

Comment: That looks like a very good display tool which I had in fact not seen before and will keep an eye on. It doesn't seem to have any support for creation updating or deleting however.

Answer (score 2):

Check out ng-admin. It supports all CRUD operations, and was built with customization in mind.

https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin

Answer (score 0):

Here is the angular version of jtable called **angular-jtable**.

**GitHub** https://github.com/pmapkiranch/angular-jtable

**Plunker**  http://plnkr.co/edit/D7oics3tl2i3elowaALu?p=preview

```html
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="jtableTestController" class="container">
     <pre>You selected {{vm.selectedrows.length}} items</pre> 
      
      <jtable items="items" options="JtableOptions" vm="vm" selecteditems="vm.selectedrows"></jtable>
    </div>
  
</div>
  </body>
```

**Result**

[image]

jtable is very handy but we miss angular version in original one so I've started new one. More features to come.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular 5, consider

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular5-data-table

If you are using AngularJS, checkout

http://ui-grid.info/

This project is part of [AngularUI](https://angular-ui.github.io/)