# Using jtable.js in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using jtable.js. I have managed to build a prototype using jquery and it works fine but now I am trying to import it in Angular. For that I am creating a directive. 
First of all the following code shows what I am doing using JQuery.

In html:-

```
<div id="mainTable"></div>
```

In Javascript:-

```
var mainTable = $("#mainTable");
// Initialize jtable
mainTable.jtable("{
title: 'Table title',
actions: {
       listAction: URL,
},
fields: {
   Child: {
       title: '',
       display: openChild, // OpenChild is a function to get child grid layout
       visibility: 'fixed'
   },
   Name: {
       title: 'Name'
   }
}
}")
```

**// Definition of OpenChild**

```
function OpenChild(childData) {
  var $img = $('<img src="imagePath"/>');
  $img.click(function(){........}
  return $img;
}
```

To use it in angular I am wrapping it in a directive which takes the jtable configuration as attribute value. Something like following:-

```
<div id="mainTable" jtable-Configuration="{
title: 'Table title',
actions: {
       listAction: URL,
},
fields: {
   Child: {
       title: '',
       display: openChild, // Where/How to define openChild in angularjs so external library (jtable.js) can call it.
       visibility: 'fixed'
   },
   Name: {
       title: 'Name'
   }
}
}"></div>
```

The problem is that I don't know how can I make jtable library to call **OpenChild** method. Where should I specify this method. Inside the directive? As a javascript function in html file?

Note that my directive is very simple:-

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('jtableConfiguration', jTableFunc);

function jTableFunc() {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A'
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).jtable(scope.$eval(attrs.jTable));
    }}();
```

Also, could anyone suggest whether this is the right approach to use a third party library?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the openChild method on the scope where you are using the directive - so it is defined in the controller for that html.

You are using scope.$eval that evaluates the arguments in the scope context, so you should be able to use methods on the scope.

see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope section on $eval

Answer (score 0):

Yes https://github.com/pmapkiranch/angular-jtable

Please refer the last post at the end for angular version of jtable

[Is there a pre-built Angular component similar to JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037926/is-there-a-pre-built-angular-component-similar-to-jtable)